# Select 3 and more duplicate rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm learning the SQL Server and I got confused while selecting 3 and more duplicate rows in the SQL Server. I need to filter my data minimum 3 and more duplicate rows by using the SQL Server and I don't know how to select them.

The table structure is:

- Date
- Hour
- ID
- WHO
- ItemNAME

I want to see 3 and more duplicate rows in Hour and ID at the same time. Could you please help me guys?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: perhaps you need to learn more about grouping and count

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get `hour`/`id` pairs with such duplicates as:

```
select hour, id
from t
group by hour, id
having count(*) >= 3;
```

If you want the original rows, there are several methods.  One uses window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by hour, id) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt >= 3;
```